# Mapster - How to access the parent object

Tags: mapster

When using Mapster I'd like to have access to the parent object when mapping the children.  How do I do this?

```cs
class Parent {
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public Child Child {get;set;}
}

class Child {
 public int ParentId {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}

...
config.NewConfig<Parent, ParentModel>()
 .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
 .Map(dest => dest.Child, src => src.Child);

config.NewConfig<Child, ChildModel>()
 .Map(dest => dest.Name, src => src.Name)
 .Map(dest => dest.ParentId, src => // How do I access the parent.Id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map child object inside parent mapping configuration.

```
config.NewConfig<Parent, ParentModel>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Child.ParentId, src => src.Id);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.